# Pattern matching data types in Haskell. Short cuts?

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching

In the following Haskell code, how can this be written more succinctly?  Is it necessary to list all four conditions, or can these be summarized by a more compact pattern?  For instance, is there a way I can take advantage of Haskell already knowing how to add a float and an int, without having to manually specify *fromIntegral*?

```
data Signal = SignalInt Int | SignalFloat Float | Empty deriving (Show)

sigAdd :: Signal -> Signal -> Signal
sigAdd (SignalInt a) (SignalInt b) = SignalInt (a + b)
sigAdd (SignalInt a) (SignalFloat b) = SignalFloat ((fromIntegral a) + b)
sigAdd (SignalFloat a) (SignalInt b) = SignalFloat (a + (fromIntegral b))
sigAdd (SignalFloat a) (SignalFloat b) = SignalFloat (a + b)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn (show (sigAdd (SignalFloat 2) (SignalInt 5)))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell does *not* know how to add a `Float` and an `Int`; it is very specific and explicit about types:

```
Prelude> (5 :: Int) + 3.5

<interactive>:1:13:
    No instance for (Fractional Int)
      arising from the literal `3.5' at <interactive>:1:13-15
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Int)
    In the second argument of `(+)', namely `3.5'
    In the expression: (5 :: Int) + 3.5
    In the definition of `it': it = (5 :: Int) + 3.5
```

Define a function `toFloatSig`:

```
toFloatSig (SignalInt a) = fromIntegral a
toFloatSig (SignalFloat a) = a
```

Then you can write:

```
sigAdd (SignalInt a) (SignalInt b) = SignalInt (a + b)
sigAdd sa sb = SignalFloat (toFloatSig sa + toFloatSig sb)
```

It might also be appropriate to make `Signal` an instance of the [`Num` class](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.4/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#7), so that you can add them directly with the `+` operator. Also, you could make the type more generic:

```
data (Num a) => Signal a = Signal a | Empty deriving (Show)
```

Comment: > sigAdd sa sb = SignalFloat (toFloatSig a + toFloatSig b)

Should this be "...(toFloatSig sa + toFloatSig sb)"?  Thanks.

Comment: Why does the "Very strong convention not to have constraints on data constructors" not hold here? Just diving into haskell, and read about this rule so I'm curious if it applies to your example (and if not - why)

Comment: @Al.G. Might be better to just leave the constraint out. Then `Signal` basically devolves into `Maybe`, which might be useful. But I'm no expert either...